# S3 consistency for sucessful read after write

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, eventual-consistency

Could not find a definitive answer here.

According to Amazon S3 docs, the caveat for read after write is if I got 404 for GET, then PUT a new object, then GET.
My question is, after I do GET a successful read,
does subsequent reads will be successful too?

Example:

```
GET key 404
PUT key 200
GET key 404 # because caveat
GET key 200
```

From now on, does any subsequent `GET key` is guaranteed to be successful?

Answer (score 2):

The caveat AWS describes in the [S3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel) suggests that they use a caching layer on top of the database they use to store details of objects in S3 like it's key and meta data.

If you do a `PUT` for a object as first operation and a `GET` afterwards, there will be a cache miss for the `GET` operation so the caching layer will fetch information about this object from the database.

If you do a `GET` before the `PUT` the caching layer will query the database, will receive the information that this object doesn't exist and cache that information, even though after the `PUT` creates the mentioned object shortly after. So the `GET` after the `PUT` will receive the information that the object doesn't exist from the cache.

That's probably why this caveat exists. Unfortunately that doesn't answer your question, because we don't know how that caching layer works. If this layer uses shared state, then you should receive a `200` response for all requests, once you received one response with `200`. My guess is that they don't use shared state for the caching layer, as that's easier to scale. Without shared state it depends on your luck, the time-to-live for items in the cache and if they employ some kind of cache invalidation for updated objects whether you receive a `200` or a `404` for requests even after the first successful `200` request.

Because the details of the inner workings of S3 are unknown I wouldn't rely on ubsequent calls to succeed, but my guess is that the probability of receiving a `404` after a successful `200` is rather low. In the end you have to decide based on your use case if and how it makes sense to account for this situation or not.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer

Snippets from the [official AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-update-strong-read-after-write-consistency/)

> **S3 is Now Strongly Consistent**
>
> After that overly-long introduction, I
> am ready to share some good news!
>
> Effective immediately, all S3 GET, PUT, and LIST operations, as well
> as operations that change object tags, ACLs, or metadata, are now
> strongly consistent. What you write is what you will read, and the
> results of a LIST will be an accurate reflection of what’s in the
> bucket. This applies to all existing and new S3 objects, works in all
> regions, and is available to you at no extra charge! There’s no impact
> on performance, you can update an object hundreds of times per second
> if you’d like, and there are no global dependencies.

Comment: Yes, once it's fully propagated, of course, but then that's largely the definition of 'propagated'. The issue is that you cannot determine when that is, with the notable exception of the PUT of a new object (as long as you did not previously HEAD or GET that same key). I'm not aware of any guarantee that an additional GET in the case in point will return 200.

Comment: And ... AWS has just changed things with [strong read after write consistency](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-update-strong-read-after-write-consistency/).